# Two Color Linear Gradient .ppm Files In C++

Tags: c++, linear-gradients

I am creating a function in C++ that creates a two color gradient .ppm file from colors and dimensions the user inputs. The main problem I have run into is the loop of the colors it seems to restart a ways into the image as seen here. [image]

when it should just look like the left portion of the image but with the same dimensions. Here is the code I am using to get the image.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Color
{
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;
};

void smoosh(int rows, int cols, Color leftColor, Color rightColor, string  filename);
int main()
{
    int y;
    int x;
    Color l;
    Color r;
    string f;
    cout << "Left Color: ";
    cin >> l.red >> l.green >> l.blue;
    cout << "\nRight Color: ";
    cin >> r.red >> r.green >> r.blue;
    cout << "\nHeight: ";
    cin >> y;
    cout << "\nWidth: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "\nFile Name: ";
    cin >> f;
    smoosh(y, x, l, r, f);


    return 0;
}
void smoosh(int rows, int cols, Color leftColor, Color rightColor, string   filename)
{
    int maxI = 256;
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(filename);
    fout << "P3\n";
    fout << cols << " " << rows << "\n" << maxI - 1 << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            fout << (leftColor.red + ((j / 255.0) * (rightColor.red - leftColor.red))) << " ";
            fout << (leftColor.green + ((j / 255.0) * (rightColor.green - leftColor.green))) << " ";
            fout << (leftColor.blue + ((j / 255.0) * (rightColor.blue - leftColor.blue)))<< " ";
        }
        fout << endl;
    }
    fout.close();
}
```

The user input values for the image above were
Left Color: 255 0 0
Right Color: 255 255 0
Height: 200
Width: 400, Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: j is the column number. You are dividing it by 255.0, which is presumably the max colour value. What is the physical meaning of this?

Answer (score 1):

I think is should be something like

```
current.red = leftcolor.red;

in the loop:

    current.red += (rightcolor.red - leftcolor.red)/cols

    fout << current.red

    ...
```